# Override bootstrap in .net core 2.0 using less

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, .net-core

In good old ASP.NET we would install Bootstrap as a NuGet package and it would install all the files in the `~/Content/bootstrap` directory. This made it easy to create a custom `bootstrap.less` file that imported Bootstrap so that we could override what we wanted while still keeping the library intact so it could be updated at any time.

For example I could do this in my custom less file to enable a special bootswatch theme with some custom variables and overrides. I could then compile it and add it to the site css.

`@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "bootstrap/_variables.less";
@import "bootstrap/_bootswatch.less";
@import "custom.less";`

In dot net core 2.0 there is no `~/Content` directory by default and css is really served from the new `wwwroot`directory. When installing Bootstrap through NuGet now, it is added as a "Dependency". I can't find a way to import the bootstrap less files as I used to though since I don't know the path, if there even is one.

I have created a custom `~/Styles/bootstrap.less` file in which I try to use the imports above but the compiler can't find them. I have found the `.less` files in `/packages/bootstrap.less.3.3.7/content/Content/bootstrap.less` in my solution root but that does not seem to be accessible to the `import`-statements.

`@import '../../packages/bootstrap.less.3.3.7/content/Content/bootstrap.less';`

The error I get is simply:

> FileError: '../../packages/bootstrap.less.3.3.7/content/Content/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.
>
> Tried - [SOLUTIONPATH]\packages\bootstrap.less.3.3.7\content\Content\bootstrap.less,
>
> ....\packages\bootstrap.less.3.3.7\content\Content\bootstrap.less in \Styles_bootstrap.less

How can I override the bootstrap less files? Do I have to download bootstrap myself into my `~/Styles/` directory to be able to import them? That would ruin the possibility of updating through NuGet :/

Comment: those paths look like `.net framework` folder structure. `.net core` uses `~/lib/bootstrap/` with bower packages

Comment: by the way `.net core` doesn't support nugets well for client side. Not sure how you got it installed. `.net core` mainly uses bower

Comment: Interesting, I just picked Bootstrap.Less from the NuGet package manager in my .net core project. I suppose that was not correct :P

Comment: when i tried client side libraries from nuget it used to show errors. .net core usually comes ready with bootstrap bower package that also contains the less. are you using visual studio 2017?

Comment: Yes, using VS Community 2017. I guess I will look into Bower. Have not used it before.

Comment: Bower is no more the recommended tool. Yarn and WebPack are the given options

Answer (score 0):

.net core has stopped supporting Nugets for client side codes. Creating a new .net core project with either vs 2017 or using the cli `dotnet new mvc` would by default include the bower packages on the wwwroot/lib folder. To manage bower packages you can right click on the project and select "manage bower packages". Also note that .net core mvc by default is only configured to use the wwwroot folder as the client side content. Besides this, the compiled views are the only other content that are given to the client. This means that and Styles or Contents folder you create wouldn't be a client side code by default. You can add theses folders in the set up but its not recommended. The js and css files can be found in folders inside wwwroot.